# Is there a way to turn off specific localized languages in Xcode for my iOS app without removing any translated files?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I have an iOS app that has 16 localized languages in it. I'd like to turn off a few localized languages (German, for example) in Xcode so that the app in German will default back to English for now until I fix some of the translations in my `strings` files in a future update.

What I don't want to do is completely remove my `strings` files from my Xcode project though, because they are mostly translated properly. I want everything to stay the same, just with specific languages turned off.

Can anyone explain how to do this?

I've noticed that when I remove languages from the Project > Localizations section, it removes the localizations for my xib files, and when I add the language back all my previous translations are gone.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me. For some reason I can't remove base language in iOS16 but it worked previously.

In your build phases create a build script and add the following:

```
# Remove German
rm -r "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/de.lproj"
# Remove base (iOS 9)
rm -r "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Base.lproj"
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437770